# Authenticating a web service for use with push notifications

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, windows-phone-7.1, mpns

For our Mango app we have enabled push notifications. But it is unauthorized. In order to have authenticated web service, we need to create and install the required certificate. We are using Tomcat as a web server. Which SSL certificate do we need to create and install and how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at [Setting Up an Authenticated Web Service to Send Push Notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941099%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) in MSDN? It tells you where to put your certificate and what to do next. [This article](http://arstechnica.com/security/news/2009/12/how-to-get-set-with-a-secure-sertificate-for-free.ars) contains some information about how to get a certificate. And the folks at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) are probably the best source to ask about installing it on your server.